# Python partial sum of dictionary values

Tags: python

I have a dictionary `dgr` of n (for this example let's just say n=10) objects named `'gr0'` up to `'gr(n-1)'` (in case n=10 up to `'gr9'`) with float values ordered to them in the following fashion:

```
dgr = {'gr0': 1.3, 'gr1': 1.2, 'gr2': 1.9, 'gr3': 2.4, 'gr4': 2.2, 'gr5': 4.2, 'gr6': 1.2, 'gr7': 5.5, 'gr8': 4.3, 'gr9': 3.2}
```

I have another dictionary

```
dy = {}
```

which is supposed to be filled as such (the 2nd line produces the to-be-fixed error):

```
for x in range(0,n):
    dy["y{0}".format(x)] = sum(dgr.values()[0,x])
```

so `'y0'` is `1.3`, but `'y3'` is `6.8` so the sum of the values of `'gr0'` up to `'gr3'`.
Summing **all** values of `gr{x}'` (so leaving `[0,x]` out) works but if I try to do the partial sums with `[0,x]` it gives me this error:

```
'dict_values' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You have an obvious error as indicated by the exception. However, it's unclear what you're trying to do . What output are you hoping for?

Comment: Indeed, the object returned by `dgr.values()` is not subscriptable. You can convert it to a list, though

Comment: Convert to list for indexable ("subscriptable") object - `sum(list(dgr.values())[0:x]` (also notice it's `0:x`, not `0,x` for slice). Please remember that dicts only keep the insertion order, so if order of your grs is messed up, so will the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help. I have added `n's` value to `10`(because you start from `0`) in the loop you can let it be `n` though):

```
for x in range(0,10): # Note: Here n = 10
    dy["y{0}".format(x)] = sum(list(dgr.values())[0:x+1])
```

Output:

```
{'y0': 1.3, 'y1': 2.5, 'y2': 4.4, 'y3': 6.800000000000001, 'y4': 9.0,
'y5': 13.2, 'y6': 14.399999999999999, 'y7': 19.9, 'y8': 24.2, 'y9': 27.4}
```

### What you were doing wrong?

You cannot subscript the dictionary values directly. Instead, try to get the values, convert them to a list, and then use slicing.
In slicing, you need to use `0:x+1` otherwise `y0` will be `0` and all following keys will have sum till `x` i.e. 1 key before than intended output. Also, use `: (colon)` for slicing and not `, (commas)`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution accomplishes what you are actually trying to do:

```
for x in range(0,n):
    dy["y{0}".format(x1)] = sum([dgr["gr{0}".format(x2)] for x2 in range(0, x+1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
dy["y{0}".format(x)] = sum(i for idx, i in enumerate(dgr.values()) if idx <= x)
```

or even avoid `dgr.values()` altogether

```
dy["y{0}".format(x)] = sum(dgr[k] for idx, k in enumerate(dgr) if idx <= x)
```

or more efficiently (for this input)

```
dy["y{0}".format(x)] = sum(tuple(dgr.values())[0:x + 1])
```

Output from printing `dy`

```
{'y0': 1.3,
 'y1': 2.5,
 'y2': 4.4,
 'y3': 6.800000000000001,
 'y4': 9.0,
 'y5': 13.2,
 'y6': 14.399999999999999,
 'y7': 19.9,
 'y8': 24.2,
 'y9': 27.4}
```

**Timings** using `%%timeit -n 1000000`.

```
# tuple 
5.03 µs ± 13.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

# list
5.45 µs ± 64.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

# enumerate (dgr.values())
10 µs ± 40.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

# enumerate (no dgr.values())
10.8 µs ± 69.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

# lancelot 
3.52 µs ± 47.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

# arnie 
3.01 µs ± 84.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slice syntax uses a comma to separate the start, end and step values. Therefore:

```
dgr = {'gr0': 1.3, 'gr1': 1.2, 'gr2': 1.9, 'gr3': 2.4, 'gr4': 2.2, 'gr5': 4.2, 'gr6': 1.2, 'gr7': 5.5, 'gr8': 4.3, 'gr9': 3.2}

vlist = list(dgr.values())

dy = {f'y{y}': sum(vlist[:y+1]) for y in range(len(vlist))}

print(dy)
```

...should give you what I *think* you're trying to achieve namely:

```
{'y0': 1.3, 'y1': 2.5, 'y2': 4.4, 'y3': 6.800000000000001, 'y4': 9.0, 'y5': 13.2, 'y6': 14.399999999999999, 'y7': 19.9, 'y8': 24.2, 'y9': 27.4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looping over the key numbers anyway, a straightforward and efficient approach is to keep track of the partial (cumulative) sum along the way:

```py
n = 10
dgr = {'gr0': 1.3, 'gr1': 1.2, 'gr2': 1.9, 'gr3': 2.4, 'gr4': 2.2, 
       'gr5': 4.2, 'gr6': 1.2, 'gr7': 5.5, 'gr8': 4.3, 'gr9': 3.2}

dy = {}
cumsum = 0

for i in range(n):
    cumsum += dgr[f"gr{i}"]
    dy[f"y{i}"] = cumsum
    
print(dy)
```

```
{'y0': 1.3, 'y1': 2.5, 'y2': 4.4, 'y3': 6.800000000000001, 'y4': 9.0,
 'y5': 13.2, 'y6': 14.399999999999999, 'y7': 19.9, 'y8': 24.2, 'y9': 27.4}
```

Answer (score 0):

dictionary is not subscriptable because it is not work like an array object. `set`, `list` and `tuple` subscriple elements so you need **values** of dictionary sample solution like that

```
dgr={'gr0': 1.3, 'gr2': 1.9, 'gr3': 2.4, 'gr1': 1.2,   'gr4': 2.2, 'gr5': 4.2, 'gr6': 1.2, 'gr7': 5.5, 'gr8': 4.3, 'gr9': 3.2}
dgr = sorted(dgr.items())
grs = [gr[1] for gr in dgr]
dy = {}
for i in range(len(grs)):
  dy[f'y{i}'] = sum(grs[0:i+1])
```